# PostgreSQL adding and transforming the info to uppercase

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to write a procedure that will change the email to uppercase when adding a client to the "clients" table. Can you please help or give some links where to find this info?
If you need any additional info will be glad to provide it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger to do this. In Postgres a trigger consists of two parts: the trigger *function* and the trigger *definition*.

The trigger function could look like this:

```
create function upper_case_email()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.email := upper(new.email);
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The `new` variable references is the just inserted row.

Details on how to write trigger functions in PL/pgSQL can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)

Once the function is created, the trigger definition defines on which table the trigger should fire and when it should fire. In this case you want a "before insert trigger" - to be able to modify the row's column value before the row is written to the table:

```
create trigger client_uppercase_email_trg
   before insert on clients
   for each row
   execute procedure upper_case_email();
```

Details about the options of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=06f44fde5c6f81af1fe46008cfbec342)

Comment: Just tried and it worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Try typing this in a browser: [PostgreSQL adding and transforming the info to uppercase](https://www.google.com/search?q=PostgreSQL+adding+and+transforming+the+info+to+uppercase)

One of the first links found is: [PostgreSQL force upper case for all data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102957/postgresql-force-upper-case-for-all-data). This has an example of how to convert all columns to uppercase.